# Как получить данные от iframe на другом домене?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, cross-origin

Есть необходимость получать значение переменной от iframe. Iframe находится на другом домене, домен мой.

Есть домен, на котором подключены push-уведомления, нужно проверять состояние подписки на уведомления с разных доменов.

Возможно ли через iframe загрузить страницу с кодом на домене *B*, который проверит подписку и вернет значение в переменной, а на домене *A* получить значение этой переменной?

Comment: window.postMessage

Comment: @AlexeyTen не подскажете пример кода? Ибо, не получается разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Вот наглядный пример https://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/lpExI

На странице, открываемой во фрейме, такой вот код для получения сообщения:

```
window.onload = function() {
// Get a reference to the <div> on the page that will display the
// message text.
var messageEle = document.getElementById('message');

// A function to process messages received by the window.
function receiveMessage(e) {
    // Check to make sure that this message came from the correct domain.
    if (e.origin !== "http://s.codepen.io")
        return;

    // Update the div element to display the message.
    messageEle.innerHTML = "Message Received: " + e.data;
}

// Setup an event listener that calls receiveMessage() when the window
// receives a new MessageEvent.
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage);
```

}

Comment: На codepen в консоли вижу такое сообщение: "can't access SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin 'https://s.codepen.io' from accessing a cross-origin frame."

Comment: Пример должен быть рабочий, попробуйте самостоятельно запустить(воспроизвести) его у себя, там сайт уже на https, а в примере http и на другом конце он ждёт http, но приходит https потому код может не сработать.

Comment: Использовал этот пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/3457907/9362608